# Android- Using Power Button as trigger to start application

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

I am trying to build an app with the ability for it to be shown over Lock Screen when the physical Power button is pressed say 2 times in quick succession or long pressed.

So far I have figured out that I need a-

1) SERVICE- I need a Service that should intercept the Power buttons pressing 2 times / long press- whether the device is locked or not
2) RECEIVER- User Broadcast Receiver to capture the broadcast intent from service and launch my main activity.

A lot of questions on SO are similar but none of them address how to do this because-
The Service cannot have methods to detect Key Events & as a result need to find some other way to figure out when Power key is being pressed. The suggested alternate is to use SCREEN ON and SCREEN OFF intents. But using them causes a problem if the service is running in background and the Screen is woken by some other app, eg an incoming call.

I have seen few apps which use Power button to start apps or activity. 
1) Press It- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incrediapp.press.it.macro.creator.time.saver&hl=en
2) Power Button Flashlight- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brink.powerbuttonflashlight&hl=en

Any ideas on how to start an app/activity over the press of Power buttons?
And then show it over the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **You can't! The system wasn't build that way.**

How ever many times when someone says: "You can't" he actually mean you can't without hacking it...

So here is an idea for a hack for you:

As you mentioned, services can't listen for key events, but Activity can. So activity is your answer.

Start your activity when the screens goes off, and kill it when it comes back. Also make it transparent just in case you get out of sync and you don't want to be spotted.

Now you got an easier problem to solve, how to trigger the power button from inside your activity.